# Cannot duplicate selection

Tags: modeling, mesh, selection-tools

I am doing this Blender Guru Tutorial  [How To make a Beer](https://youtu.be/Xbc3KMIOuKM?t=1122). At about 18:30 minutes Blender Guru is making a duplicate of a selection (that has to become the beer in the glass).

I am trying to do the same but somehow I cannot make the duplicate.
Here is my **[blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxaxzcca7foxyr5/glass-of-beer-01.blend?dl=0)**. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You have proportional editing on (the blue icon in the 3d view header) with a large proportional size (a large circle that appears when you try to transform) so when you try to move the duplicate mesh it moves the entire object and thus appears to have no effect, toggle it on/off with <kbd>O</kbd> or by going to the menu and choosing *Disable*.

[image]

After that to duplicate and separate, use <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>, confirm with left click and then press <kbd>P</kbd> *> Selection*.

Comment: thanks for your reaction. When I disable Proportional Editing I still cannot make the duplicate ???

Comment: @JanScherders in the file you sent you already have the selection, see the last sentence in my answer.

Comment: I did what you say ...open file, disable Proportional Editing, Shift D ... but it does not work.  I am trying for hours now, pfff ;)

Comment: @JanScherders I understand the frustration when simple things don't work ;), join [me in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm)

Comment: I know I have to do Shift D and Separate Selection but somehow the duplication does not work

Comment: @JanScherders I gave you write access, you should be able to speak now.